# Rotate instantiated prefabs

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm instantiating prefabs in a circle around a central point via the following code...

```
#pragma strict

var numPoints : int = 7;
var radiusX : int;
var radiusY : int;
var chair : Transform;

function Start () {
    distributeFields();
}

function distributeFields() {
    var centrePos = Vector3(-350,24,-490);
    for (var pointNum = 0; pointNum < numPoints; pointNum++)
    {
        var i = (pointNum * 1.0) / numPoints;
        var angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2;
        var x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radiusX;
        var z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radiusY;
        var pos = Vector3(x, 0, z) + centrePos;
        Instantiate(chair, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(pos));
    } 
}
```

I want each prefab to face the center, but they are all rotating in the same direction. I assume that each iteration is rotating all "chair" prefabs to the current iteration's rotation. Anything I'm doing clearly wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that all of the chairs are now looking away from the origin and that is why they seem to look into same direction. This is the case because `Quaternion.LookRotation` gets the chair's position vector as input.

If I understand correctly the desired input is vector from the chair to the `centrePos`. This can be done by changing the instantiate line to this:

```
    Instantiate(chair, pos, Quaternion.LookRotation(-Vector3(x, 0, z)));
```